# initializing repo

Tags: android, git, repository

once I give

```
repo init -u git://github.com/MIPS/manifests.git -b mips-gingerbread-r1
```

it says

```
"repo has been initialized to /home/user1".
```

I want to change this directory(to /home/user1/myproject). How do I do it?

I also have a local_manifest.xml which i need to use with repo to update the source tree. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

A `repo init` is done in the current working directory.

So the simplest way would simply to repeat your command in the `/home/user1/myproject`, that way all files are updated accordingly.

Comment: I did that but still it didn't change. Then I did a "rm -rf ~/.repo" and then tried in /home/user1/myproject. It worked!

Comment: @user633659: you mean you had to delete `~/.repo` first before it could work?